# Scroll Instagram page again and again using loop python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, scroll, infinite-scroll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0N69.png)I want to scroll the Instagram page that dynamically loaded, so I want to scroll how much I wanted is it possible to use loops and any other way

```
        while scroll < 3:  # Add follwers how much u want to scrape
         driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
         scroll+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use loops and any other way

You can use a for loop

```
for i in range(3):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
```

function recursion

```
def loop(i):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    if i > 0:
        return loop(i-1)
```

or just use a while loop as your currently using.

Comment: ill tried but it not worked on instagrame page